# Keeping track of "read" commits in magit?

Tags: magit

When viewing commits in magit's log view, is there a way to treat commits in magit in a similar way to email?

Where I can track their "read" status? (set unread, mark as read... etc).

Is this already implemented? Or is this something that should be implemented in a new package?

---

Note that any kind of commit-tagging mechanism would probably be sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This package: [magit-commit-mark](https://gitlab.com/ideasman42/emacs-magit-commit-mark) keeps track of read commits (as well as the ability to star and set commits as urgent).

If you have the melpa repository setup, the package can be setup as follows:

```el
(use-package magit-commit-mark
  :commands (magit-commit-mark-mode))

(eval-after-load 'magit
  (add-hook 'magit-mode-hook 'magit-commit-mark-mode))
```

---

*Created this package after asking here.*

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. And also, I must add, what strange feature that would be :)

Comment: When working on active projects, it can be difficult to keep track of commits that have been made, currently I'm using an email client to do this, but would prefer to use magit - if this one feature can be made to work.

I'd assume this would be best implemented as a separate package then.

Comment: It's not enough to read the commits you checkedout to your working copy? Just let the rest of the commits, up to head, stay in you local repo?

Comment: I tried this but with over 200 commits weekly, if you get behind it can be difficult to remember which ones have been checked, especially if you're not reading them in order.